# mean of copula parameters and the kendall taus over replicated simulation

Tags: copula

Suppose that I have a simulation data (1000 repeated). Assume further that I have simulated the data from copula models. Then, I would like to test my algorithm (to estimate the copula parameters). Assume that I find the mean over the repeated simulation. So, do you think it is enough to find the mean of the copula parameters to find the mean of the corresponding Kendall's tau or do I need to find the mean of Kendall taus explicitly? The reason for asking this question is that I have already worked with many many simulated data (for different models). And for each model, I have only computed the mean of the theta. Now, I would like to find the mean of Kendall's tau. However, this will take a lot of time. So, I think I can find the mean of Kendall's tau by using a mean of the theta. Is that OK?

Comment: You should explain what copula you are simulating, what theta is and what the relation is between theta and Kendall's tau.

Comment: @gg   I am using different copula families but all they are commonly used, for example, Frank, Clayton and so on.